# woocommerce coupon in cart page like the one in checkout

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, cart, coupon

I'm trying to copy the coupon form from the checkout page to the cart page.
In the checkout page is the coupon field displayed as a hidden element, that it's shown after a click on a url.

I've managed to move the field with,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' );
```

but I've noticed that the javascript is missing and maybe some css. Should I just copy them in the cart page, or is there a better solution?

Thanks!